# In how many ways can five-digit numbers be formed by using digits $0,2,4,6,8$ such that the numbers are divisible by $8$?

Tags: permutations

> In how many ways can five-digit numbers be formed by using digits $0,2,4,6,8$ such that the numbers are divisible by $8$?

Assume the case in which repetition is not allowed

Our Approach:

Case1: When repetition is not allowed.

We start to make pairs of combinations such that they are divisible by $8$ and left over number can be selected in the following ways also.

Is there any other approach (without making cases as it can be too long) through which I can solve this problem?

Comment: The approach by cases isn't really that long, for instance the only possible last digits are $0,4,8$ and the only possible last two digits combinations are $08, 24, 40, 48, 64, 80$, of which all have exactly the same possible statement that the remaining digits can be in any combination.  With repeated digits, the only additions to the possible-last digits list are $00, 88$.

Comment: Are leading zeros allowed ?

Comment: @Peter Leading zeros means A number that starts with 0?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: No,How could that be a 5 digit number then?

Comment: @abiessu why you have considered the last 2 digits.Last 3 digits are used to check divisibility by 8 for example i was using 024,048,064,208,240,248,264,280 etc that is why i was telling it is too long.

Comment: You only need two digits, because all the digits are even.  In other words, $8\mid 200$, and therefore adding $200$ to any $2$-digit number does not change whether it is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Since all the digits have to be even, any possible number is divisible
       by $8$, if and only if the last two digits form a number divisible by $8$.

Comment: for divisibility by 8 it should be last 3 digit number

Comment: Consider, that $200$ is divisibel by $8$, so here two digits are sufficient.

Comment: But Repeatition of digits is not allowed

Comment: I mean, two digits are sufficient to check the divisibility because $200$ is divisible by $8$. For example $20648$ is divisible by $8$ because $48$ is divisible by $8$.

Comment: Okay you mean using 0,2,4,6,8 by 2 is sufficient?

Comment: According to my PARI/GP-program, the numbers of ways should be $800$ and $30$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27472/discussion-between-justin-takro-and-peter).

Comment: @justintakro takro did you receive my invitation for a new chat-room ?